# Может ли кнопка submit быть перед формой?

Tags: php, html

В смысле на странице сначала объявляется кнопка субмит а потом ниже идет форма при том что кнопке присвоен `id` формы!?

Comment: @DanteLoL а что мешает вам это проверить?

Comment: Боюсь) мне бы хоть чуть быть уверенным) простос БД работаю и там исправлятьпридется)

Comment: интересно, какое имеет отношение положение кнопки по отношению к базе?

А вот то, что у кнопки id такой же как и у формы...

Но по факту, используйте javascript и хоть две кнопки + три картинки нужно будет нажимать для submit'а.

Comment: >простос БД работаю и там исправлятьпридется)

а как все эти ваши сабмиты относятся к БД? Или вы даже в тестовых целях все сразу пишете в продакшн?

Comment: и еще, что значит вот это: 

>при том что кнопке присвоен id формы!?

а вообще [вот][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag

Comment: Осеннее обострение...

Comment: @Palmervan вроде еще рано) К тому же там обычно вопросы про "как мне сделать односвязный список"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get" id="form1">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
</form>

<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если submit внутри <form>, то будет работать, если нет, то можно привязать при помощи js, а-ля :

```
<input type="button" onclick="form.submit(); return false;" />
<form name="form">
 <!-- Something -->
</form>
```